# Where should I add project level dependencies for firebase in new Android Studio projects

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I created an Android project from Android Studio Bumblebee and I am trying to integrate Firebase into it. As per the documentation from Firebase, I should add some project level and module level dependencies which are shown below.

[image]

When I go to my project level Gradle file it is something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So my question is, where should I add these dependencies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it by adding build script in the top

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the `google()` repositories mentioned can be excluded as its there by default.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following piece of code

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

I'm sorry that you ran into this, the Firebase console was using the older `buildscript` syntax (pre-Bumblebee) for these instructions. As of June 2023, it has been updated to use the `plugins` syntax, so the correct syntax to add the plugin in your `<project>/build.gradle` file would be:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

    // Add the Google services plugin ⬇️
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}

// ...
```

And in your `<project>/app/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

    // Apply the Google services plugin ⬇️
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Screenshot of the new console instructions for reference:

[image: Firebase console]