# Build Gradle looks different. How to I install Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

Im new to android studio and i was trying to install firebase for my application. The problem is my Project:Gradle looks different than the one from firebase website:

```
Project-level build.gradle (<project>/build.gradle):
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    ...
  }
}
```

my  Project:Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
`

id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false`

id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to add buildscript and all projects inside there but with no sucess.

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    
    }
    dependencies {
    
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    
    }

}

plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Getting this error :

```
Build file 'C:\\Users\\User\\finalYearProject\\build.gradle' line: 28

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'finalYearProject'.

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

What should i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I add project level dependencies for firebase in new Android Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549716/where-should-i-add-project-level-dependencies-for-firebase-in-new-android-studio)

Comment: You should follow instruction through this it will be more easy to you ...                      https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup