# facing difficulty to add firebase json file to gradle project level in latest android version

Tags: android, json, firebase

I am trying to connect my app with firebase but i am facing difficulty to add firebase json file to gradle project level in latest android version. Firebase instructions ask to paste the code into the gradle project level under all projects and dependencies but my gradle project level does not have this tags.This is the firebase dependency
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

Comment: Have you added google-services.json file in app level directory ?

Comment: If you have added google-services.json file in app level directory, then what's the issue?

Comment: FIREBASE INSTRUCT TO ADD FOLLOWING THING IN BUILD.GRADLE PROJECT LEVEL BUT MY ANDROID STUDIO IS LATEST AND DOES NOT HAVE THESE TAGS dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I add project level dependencies for firebase in new Android Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549716/where-should-i-add-project-level-dependencies-for-firebase-in-new-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Select project instead of android and paste your files in app folder.

[image]

Comment: INSTRUCTION FROM FIREBASE To make the google-services.json config values accessible to Firebase SDKs, you need the Google services Gradle plug-in.

Add the plug-in as a buildscript dependency to your project-level build.gradle file:
buildscript {
  repositories {   
  }
  dependencies {
   NOTE: WHERE TO ADD FOLLOWING THING BECAUSE MY ANDROID STUDIO IS LATEST AND DOES NOT HAVE THESE TAGS IN BUILD.GRADLE IN PROJECT LEVEL 
   
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
       google() mavenCentral()
  }
}

Comment: any idea for my query

Comment: I am not getting what your issue is. which way do you connect your project to firebase

Comment: buildscript {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
} dependencies {
// Add dependency for Google services Gradle plugin
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
NOTE: FIREBASE INSTRUCT TO ADD THIS DEPENDENCY IN BUILD.GRADLE IN PROJECT LEVEL BUT IN MY PROJECT LEVEL buildscript {
repositories { allprojects {
repositories {
}
ARE NOT AVAILABLE . MY BUILD.GRADLE OF PROJECT LEVEL IS LIKE THIS
plugins{
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}